# h264 provider start

Tags: asp.net, video-processing, h.264

i am trying to make ffmpeg or x264 provider that will encode videos.. Well i have been looking at some tools and such and. i don't know..
I would need to make my own api. I have done the same 4 ffmpeg for flv1 but h264 seems much different..

can anyone give me some basics where and how to start?

Answer (score 0):

Ah.. as i don't have any answers and i did resolve this.. here is what i did do..
After loosing a lot of time, downloading many files, reading unclear documentation and so on and so on...

best and most important thing here is avisynth tool that can load any kind of video under directshow - do really a lot (using it's own script language) and then send that script to x264.exe encoder that will create video, which u will need to include with mp3 (also extracted by using avisynth plugin) and wrap it into mp4 file with mp4box.exe.

All this jobs are done by running process from .net that will return output.

My list of tools is:
avisynth - best thing for video ever made
ffmpeg - to get images out but u can use it for other things if u like
x264 - to get x264 video out from avs (avisynth script)
mp3box - to combine 264 file with mp3 into h264
soundout - avi synth plugin to extract mp3 sound from avisynth video
yadif - avi synth plugin to do some tihngs

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be to use Mencoder.

Try to find a binary version that has pre-compiled support for x264 (or compile your own!) in order to use it for H.264 encoding. In order to see what things your Mencoder binary support, try the command

```
mencoder -ovc help
```

If you get x264 somewhere in that list, you are good to go.

After that, you can use Mencoder to transcode any kind of video to H.264. Please check the mencoder manual here to get started:

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-x264.html